# Bootstrap Jumbotron dock image to bottom

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following issue.

I have a headline in a jumbotron with Boostrap. Now I want to dock a image centered to the bottom.

I tried some other ways shown on stackoverflow but nothing seems to work.

Here is the code: http://jsfiddle.net/S298j/3/

Code Issue:

```
<div class="jumbotron-main">
    <h1>
            HERE IS MY HEADLINE
    </h1><br>
    <h2>
        HERE IS MY SUB HEADLINE
        </h2>
  <img src="imageskIsFb.png"/> 
 </div>
```

Comment: Are you trying to fix the image to the bottom of the jumbotron or the window?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:
Wrap your img in a container like so, with the class of "center-block".

```
<div class="center-block">
  <img  src="http://i.epvpimg.com/kIsFb.png" />
</div>
```

This will center align the img below the heading text.
Next add some custom styling. This code gets you close. Play with the dimensions.

```
.jumbotron-main img {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 600px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<title>test</title>
<head>
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <!-- jQuery library -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
    <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <style type="text/css">
        .jumbotron-head {
            background-color: #242729;
            height: 80px;
            margin: auto;
            background-size: cover;
            }
    </style>
</head>
<body style="background-color: #C6491A;">
    <div class="jumbotron-head">
        <h1 class="text-center" style="font-size:80px;color:white;">Guild Hosting</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
        <h1 class="text-center"style="color:white;">HERE IS MY HEADLINE</h1>
         <h2 class="text-center"style="color:white;">HERE IS MY SUB HEADLINE</h2>
          <img src="http://i.epvpimg.com/kIsFb.png" style="padding-top:170px;padding-right:50px;" align="middle"/> 
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```